# Как раскрасить все вершины буфера разными цветами с переливами?

Tags: opengl, шейдеры

На картинке маленький (черный) квадрат, должен быть переливающемся (нарисован переходящими цветами от одного к другому) но почему то он просто черный. При этом он отрисовался, а не выкинул ошибку.

Вот код отрисовки маленького черного квадрата.

```
void My_TwoSquares()
{
    GLfloat vertires[] =
    {
        // четыре точки для постройки двух треуголов
        //        -0.6f, 0.6f, 0.0f,
        -0.2f, -0.2f, 0.0f,
        -0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f,
        0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f,
        0.2f, -0.2f, 0.0f,
    };
    // цвет
    GLfloat cwet[] = {
        // цвет
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLuint indices[] =
    {
        0,1,2, // первый треугольник
        0,2,3  // второй треугольник
    };

    // единая переменная для обхода позиций
    GLuint iboHandle;
    // создаём единую переменную для хранения дескриптора
    GLuint vaoHandle;
    // Создаём и заполняем буферные обьекты
    GLuint vboHandles[2];
    glGenBuffers(2, vboHandles);
    GLuint positionBufferHandle = vboHandles[0];
    GLuint colorBufferHandle = vboHandles[1];

    // заполнить буфер координат
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertires, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // заполнить буфер цветов
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12*sizeof(GLfloat), cwet, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Создать обьект массива вершин
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoHandle);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);

    // Активировать массивы вершинных атрибутов
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Координаты вершины
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // Цвет вершины

//    glBindAttribLocation(vboHandles, 0, "VertexPosition");
//    glBindAttribLocation(vboHandles, 1, "VertexColor");

    // Закрепить индекс 0 за буфером с координатами
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    // Закрепить индекс 1 за буфером с цветом
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    // Создём и закрепляем обходной(позиционный) буфер
    glGenBuffers(1, &iboHandle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    ShaderProgram shaderprogram;
    shaderprogram.loadShaders("basic.vert", "basic.frag");
    shaderprogram.use();

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

}
```

**basic.vert**

```
 #version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;

uniform vec2 posOffset;

void main()
{
        gl_Position = vec4(pos.x + posOffset.x, pos.y + posOffset.y, pos.z, 1.0);
}
```

**basic.frag**

```
#version 330 core

uniform vec4 vertColor;
out vec4 frag_color;

void main()
{
    frag_color = vertColor;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Починил :3

Надо было изменить шейдеры. Отказаться от переменной uniform и теперь обязательно стоит к каждой вершине положения иметь и вершину цвета (в общем два массива (буфера)).

Вот тут [более подробный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083836/color-does-not-work-in-starting-examples-opengl) (но , увы на английском ).

Код от рисовки маленького квадрата не изменился.

Вот измененный код "теневых программ" :

**basic.vert**

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;

out vec3 vColor;

uniform vec2 posOffset;

void main()
{
    vColor      = color;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x + posOffset.x, pos.y + posOffset.y, pos.z, 1.0);
}
```

**basic.frag**

## version 330 core

```
in  vec3 vColor;
out vec4 frag_color;

void main()
{
    frag_color = vec4(vColor.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]